# Did Jud bury his wife at that place?

Tags: plot-explanation, pet-sematary-2019

In *Pet Sematary* (2019), Jud resurrects his doggo. At a point in the film, zombie-Ellie takes the shape of his wife and says that both Ellie and his wife are burning in hell and suffering.

My interpretation was that zombie-Ellie was just mentally torturing Jud. He didn't resurrect his wife, zombie-Ellie was just describing after-life as hellish. My friends disagreed, and said Jud had brought back his wife and eventually killed her again, and that's the hell zombie-Ellie had described.

Having never read the book, is there confirmation anywhere (or does the movie heavily imply something) regarding whether Jud resurrected (or not) his wife?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the book, Jud had only resurrected his dog, and not his wife, especially since there is an instance in the book of a father bringing back his adult son that Jud knows about that went horribly wrong that is alluded to in the movie from an old news article of a missing body.

Nowhere in the movie does it imply that he ever resurrected his wife, it is pure conjecture on the part of your friends.

Answer (score 0):

The 2019 film diverges significantly from the book. The book doesn't have zombie-Ellie (or zombie-Gage, as it was in the book) transforming into anything else, nor is there any mention of Jud burying anyone in the MicMac cemetery.

Sorry to disappoint.

Comment: While this answer makes it clear the book and movie diverge, it doesn't answer my question regarding the movie

Answer (score -1):

Actually the movie does infer that. It does this when

> Ellie is stabbing him.

It infers he did this by Ellie's words. It does not say he did but it infers he did.

Comment: _How_ does it infer it though? Please [edit] your answer to explain - this is too thin right now.